# How do modules in ocLazyLoad loaded, parallel or in sequence?

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, oclazyload

I'm using [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) library to achieve lazy loading for all dependencies in my project. I know that by default files are loaded in parallel and to make it loaded in sequence I should use `serie:true` https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/47

From [this thread](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/34) I understand that I can load modules in series:

> Yes the files are loaded in parallel, if you want to multiple modules
>   at the same time and that they require one another you either need to
>   define them in different object params:

```
$ocLazyLoad.load([{
    name: 'TestModule',
    files: ['testModule.js', 'testModuleCtrl.js', 'testModuleService.js']
},{
    name: 'AnotherModule',
    files: ['anotherModule.js']
}]);
```

Now I try to load all dependencies required for FullCalendar in my application, there's my ocLazyLoad config file:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
         debug: true,
         modules: [{
                name: 'ngCkeditor',
                files: [
                            'resources/bower_components/ng-ckeditor/libs/ckeditor/ckeditor.js',
                            'resources/bower_components/ng-ckeditor/ng-ckeditor.min.js',
                            'resources/bower_components/ng-ckeditor/ng-ckeditor.css'
                        ],
                serie: true
         },{
                name: 'ui.calendar',
                files: [
                        'resources/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js',
                        'resources/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/lang/he.js',
                        'resources/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/gcal.js',
                        'resources/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js',
                        'resources/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css'
                        ],
                serie: true
         },{
                name: 'ngFileUpload',
                files: [
                            'resources/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js'
                        ]
         },{
                name: 'momentjs',
                files: [
                            'resources/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js'
                        ]
         }]
    });
```

And this is part of my router:

```
.state('schedule',{
            url: '/schedule',
            controller:     'ScheduleController',
            templateUrl:    'schedule.html',
            resolve: {
                  loginRequired: loginRequired,
                  loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                      // you can lazy load files for an existing module
                             return $ocLazyLoad.load(['momentjs','ui.calendar','ngCkeditor']);
                   }]
            }
        })
```

Despite that module `'momentjs'` defined at first place I still get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

If I put `moment.js` in `'ui.calendar'` module it works, but I'd like to load it separately because I have another views in my application where I use only moment.js and doesn't need all dependencies.

So, my question is, how to make moduls (not files) to be loaded in a serie, not files or if they already loaded in a serie, what can cause to my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use amers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34754539/5058677) when you want to load modules one after another in each separate state. 
Put:

```
$ocLazyLoad.load(['momentjs','ui.calendar','ngCkeditor'], 
    {serie: true}).then(function() {
     // done..
});
```

If you want always to load modules in a serie you can set globally parameter `serie`:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    serie: true,
    modules: [{
        ...
    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it:

```
   $ocLazyLoad.load(['momentjs','ui.calendar','ngCkeditor'], {serie: true}).then(function() {
         // done..
    });
```